# In jQuery how to get data-attribute from a parent

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container" data-step="a_1">
    <div class="mx-auto col-10">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light ls1">Question 1</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-10 mb-5">
                <div data-next="item1">
                    <input id="radio-1" class="radio-style" type="radio" name="question1[]" value="value1" class="required">
                    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-style-1-label">Item 1</label>
                </div>
                <div data-next="item2">
                    <input id="radio-2" class="radio-style" type="radio" name="question1[]" value="value2" class="required">
                    <label for="radio-2" class="radio-style-1-label">Item 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="button button-border font-weight-medium button-circle" data-action="validate-step">Next »</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click on `Next »` I want to be able to get the `data-next` of the checked element.

This is what I tried:

```
$('a[data-action="validate-step"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    item = $(this).closest('.container').data('step');

    name  = $(item).prop('checked').closest('div').data('name');
    steps = $(item).prop('checked').closest('div').data('steps');
    next  = $(item).prop('checked').closest('div').data('next');

    alert(name);
    alert(steps);
    alert(next);    
});
```

But I have this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$(item).prop('checked').closest')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read the docs for `prop()`. It doesn't do what you are trying to use it for

Comment: Also note that `.data("step")` returns a `"a_1"` and `$("a_1")` isn't going to find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the parent container in a variable, then navigate to a checked child checkbox with `:checked`, and then you can get to its parent and check its data:

```js
$('a[data-action="validate-step"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const container = $(this).closest('.container');
    const checkbox = container.find(':checked');
    const checkboxParent = checkbox.parent();
    console.log(checkboxParent.data('next'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-step="a_1">
    <div class="mx-auto col-10">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light ls1">Question 1</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-10 mb-5">
                <div data-next="item1">
                    <input id="radio-1" class="radio-style" type="radio" name="question1[]" value="value1" class="required">
                    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-style-1-label">Item 1</label>
                </div>
                <div data-next="item2">
                    <input id="radio-2" class="radio-style" type="radio" name="question1[]" value="value2" class="required">
                    <label for="radio-2" class="radio-style-1-label">Item 2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="button button-border font-weight-medium button-circle" data-action="validate-step">Next »</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```js
$('a[data-action="validate-step"]').click(function(event) {
  var checked = $(this).prev().find('[data-next]').has(':checked').data('next');
  console.log(checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-step="a_1">
  <div class="mx-auto col-10">
    <h1 class="font-weight-light ls1">Question 1</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-10 mb-5">
        <div data-next="item1">
          <input id="radio-1" class="radio-style" type="radio" name="question1[]" value="value1" class="required">
          <label for="radio-1" class="radio-style-1-label">Item 1</label>
        </div>
        <div data-next="item2">
          <input id="radio-2" class="radio-style" type="radio" name="question1[]" value="value2" class="required">
          <label for="radio-2" class="radio-style-1-label">Item 2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="button button-border font-weight-medium button-circle" data-action="validate-step">Next »</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.attr("data-next")` with `data-` attributes and jquery, always use `.data("next")` (unless there's a *really* good, specific reason not to) otherwise you'll just get confused when `.data("next", value)` doesn't come back when you use `.attr("data-next")`